# Vue: Using Vue Transitions with v-if/else?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-transitions

I have components structured like this:

```
   <component-1 
       v-if="this.showData"
    ></component-1>
    
    <component-2
       v-else
    ></compoment-2>
```

I would like to wrap a transition around each one.  Is my only option explicitly dropping the `v-else` and checking `"v-if="!this.showData"` like:

```
   <transition name="fade>
      <component-1 
          v-if="this.showData"
       ></component-1>
   </transition>
    
   <transition name="fade>
      <component-2 
          v-if="!this.showData"
       ></component-1>
   </transition>
```

or is there another way I can keep my v-if/else -- it just feels cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make if/else on transition component

```
<transition name="fade" v-if="this.showData">
  <component-1></component-1>
</transition>
    
<transition name="fade" v-else>
  <component-2></component-1>
</transition>
```

or move your components under transition

```
<transition name="fade">
  <component-1 v-if="this.showData"></component-1>
  <component-2 v-else></component-1>
</transition>
```

Comment: Don't forget to use key attributes if transitions are applying for the same tag names. Refer: [Vue 2 Transition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230103/8031025)

Answer (score 1):

```
<transition name="fade">
  <component-1 v-if="this.showData" />
  <component-2 v-else />
</transition>
```

actually you no need to call `this` in template html.

`v-if="this.showData"`

can be like this:

`v-if="showData"`

Comment: there is never a need for `this` at all in the template?

Comment: Ya. I never found `this` in template in  vue doc.